# why I got versionCode and versionName is not equal AndroidManifest

Tags: android, manifest

I try to get version code and name like this:

```
class Main {
  /*get version info */
  List item

  public void getVersionInfo(Context context){
    PackageManager mPKM = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo mInfo = PKM.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),0);
        versionName = mInfo.versionName;
        int versionCode = mInfo.versionCode;
      } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the version name and code are not equal to the manifest file. what could be the problem?

Comment: which IDE are you working on? are you using gradle?

Comment: because i build the project in Gradle, so need write versionCode ande versionName in build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Although your question isn't stated very clearly, I think I know what you mean. You want to ask why the version code and version name is not equal, right?

Because they would not be equal in most times. Let me explain what they are. Lets say that you have an app and you release it for the first time. So it is the first release and the *version code* is 1. The *version name* maybe 1.0. And now you updated your app and release it for the second time. Now the *version code* is 2. But the *version name* can be anything. Maybe your new version is 1.1 or 1.0.1 or 2.0 or whatever. Whatever the *version name* is, the *version code* is always 2 on the second time you release it.

Now that you know this, you should understand why they are different.